# MySQL find multiple records by two columns

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns, propel

Let's say I have an array as follows (ID => Type):

```
$contentIndexes = [
    32 => 'news', 
    40 => 'blog', 
    68 => 'blog', 
    109 => 'document', 
    124 => 'news'
]
```

And the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ContentIndex` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ItemID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ItemType` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    //...
);
```

How would I retrieve each `ContentIndex` based on the combination of the 'ItemID' and 'ItemType' columns (preferably with just one query).

Using `WHERE IN` is not an option since it wouldn't take the combination in consideration:

```
ContentIndexQuery::create()
    ->filterByItemID(array_keys($contentIndexes))
    ->filterByItemType($contentIndexes)
    ->find();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Propel syntax, but the basic SQL syntax would be with `OR`.

```
WHERE ((ItemID = 32 AND ItemType = 'news')
        OR
       (ItemID = 40 AND ItemType = 'blog')
        OR
       (ItemID = 68 AND ItemType = 'blog')
        OR
       (ItemID = 109 AND ItemType = 'document')
        OR
       (ItemID = 124 AND ItemType = 'news')
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

For any Propel users encountering this problem in the future, this is what I came up with to create a query as Barmar stated:

```
$items = ContentIndexQuery::create();
$i = 0;

foreach ($contentIndexes as $id = > $type) {
    if ($i > 0) $items->_or();

    $items->condition('cond1'.$i, ContentIndexTableMap::COL_ITEM_ID . ' = ?', $id)
          ->condition('cond2'.$i, ContentIndexTableMap::COL_ITEM_TYPE . ' = ?', $type)
          ->where(['cond1'.$i, 'cond2'.$i], 'AND');

    $i += 1;
}

$items = $items->find()->getData();
```